# How to read a table data from Images using Tesseract OCR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tesseract

Is anyone aware how read & parse any table data from the image. I am using asp.net application & I have successfully read data using Tesseract-OCR API but not able to read the table from Image.

Please give solution with c# code.

Comment: Newer versions of Tesseract don't do any layout analysis. It will just return one string ignoring anything like cell boundaries or columns. An example image would help to give more specific hints.

Comment: you get the solution of it ? - Shivam Srivastava